# Image doesn't show properly when sent in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, images

When I paste an image into an email it gets sent like shown in the image below. As you can see, the outline shows the entire image, but the content is pushed up into the corner.

It looks OK when I send it, but it appears like the image below both in the sent-folder and at the receiving end.

I've tried with images of varying size. For small images the entire image is blank, and for large images it's moved abit. It's not always the same amount of white on the sides, nor the same amount of the real image shown.

It worked a week ago.

Does anyone know what might cause this, and how it can be fixed?

System:

- Outlook v2012 build 13530.20376
- Windows 10 Pro

[image]

Comment: From which program are you pasting? How are you pasting (Ctrl-V or menu)? Does this happen with all images? If not, can you post an example of such an image.

Comment: It happens with both Greenshot and Window's Snip and Sketch. It happens to all images as far as I can tell.

Comment: Many accounts relate the problem to bad DPI attribute of the pasted image. Try: (1) Use "Paste as bitmap", (2) Pass the image through an image editor and check the DPI. Perhaps copy-paste from the image editor will work better.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your build number is not the latest, so firstly I would suggest you to upgrade your Outlook to the latest version to avoid possible version-related issue. And I tried a few tests in Outlook 365 Version 2012 Build 13530.20440, cannot reproduce your issue.

By the way, can images received from others display normally?

> It looks OK when I send it, but it appears like the image below both in the sent-folder and at the receiving end.

There could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and do the same sending test to see if the issue continues.